# How can I track current Follow/Unfollow events on Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

[Github API V3 Documenatation](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#followevent) states:

> **FollowEvent**
>
> Triggered when a user follows another user.
>
> Events of this type are no longer created, but it’s possible that they
>   exist in timelines of some users.

Beside of wondering why those events are not being created, is there other way I can track when and who does user decide follow (and unfollow) through the github API?

Comment: you will need to watch the data for changes like i did here https://starhub-notifier.duckdns.org/

Answer (score 1):

The only other API I can think of around this is the [List users followed by another user](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/#list-users-followed-by-another-user) endpoint, but that won't give you timestamps and unfollow events - you'd have to do that work yourself...